# python tree.xpath return empty list

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping

I'm having hard time figuring out why the tree.xpath method displayed in my code below would return an empty list. 
In this example, I'm just trying to retrieve the stock tickers under the "People also Watch" banner in yahoo finance which seems pretty trivial but was unable to make it work so far.

I'm copying the xpath from the inspect element page. Have also tried changing the xpath manually such as removing 'tbody', but it didn't work neither.
Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you

````
import requests
from lxml import html


ticker = 'TSLA'
url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/'+str(ticker)+'?p='+str(ticker)
page = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
tree.xpath('//*[@id="rec-by-symbol"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a')```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to parse page, that is being rendrered to HTML code by browser. If you open page's source code - you will see, that it has one big script tag with all data to be renderer.

You have two ways how to deal with this situation:

***1. Render page and run XPathes in it.***

It is about opening page in browser, getting rendered DOM from it and running XPath.

Best tool to use in this case - selenium with some kind of webdriver (util to control browser via python code)

Example code for your situation:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

ticker = 'TSLA'
url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/'+str(ticker)+'?p='+str(ticker)
driver.get(url)

xpath = '//*[@id="rec-by-symbol"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a'
found_nodes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)

for node in found_nodes:
    print(node.text)

driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

But you need to install selenium and download proper driver. For Chrome I used in example it will be chromedriver (you can get it here: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/):

```
pip install selenium
```

***2. Parse script into Object (especially node root.App.main) and work with it***

It is more complicated way, but without need of browser.

Workflow:

```
a. Download page via requests;
b. Get script with target data (via regular expressions);
c. load root.App.main as json Object (json.loads method);
d. Find necessary nodes in Object.
```

I won't provide any code for this case, because it requires to write almost whole parser for your task.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need any side packages as selenium and you want to use only requests and lxml, as i did by myself. I have used **regex** for such things:

for example, you could just look at page.context and find there some json structure that you need from the site like:

```
"NFLX":{"sourceInterval":15,"regularMarketOpen":{"raw":338.68,"fmt":"338.68"},"exchange":"NMS","regularMarketTime":{"raw":1579122001,"fmt":"4:00PM EST"},"fiftyTwoWeekRange":{"raw":"252.28 - 385.99","fmt":"252.28 - 385.99"},
```

and here you could find more info than just from lxml, but it could be much harder