# How to use selenium for webscraping google flights?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to pull the airline names and prices of a specific flight. I'm having trouble with the x.path and/or using the right html tags because when I run the code below, all I get back is 14 empty lists.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from lxml import html
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\14074\Python\chromedriver")
URL = 'https://www.google.com/travel/flights/searchtfs=CBwQAhopagwIAxIIL20vMHBseTASCjIwMjEtMTItMjNyDQgDEgkvbS8wMWYwOHIaKWoNCAMSCS9tLzAxZjA4chIKMjAyMS0xMi0yN3IMCAMSCC9tLzBwbHkwcAGCAQsI____________AUABSAGYAQE&tfu=EgYIAhAAGAA'

driver.get(URL)

sleep(1)

tree = html.fromstring(driver.page_source)

for flight_tree in tree.xpath('//div[@class="TQqf0e sSHqwe tPgKwe ogfYpf"]'):
     title = flight_tree.xpath('.//*[@id="yDmH0d"]/c-wiz[2]/div/div[2]/div/c-wiz/div/c-wiz/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[6]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/span/text()')
     price = flight_tree.xpath('.//span[contains(@data-gs, "CjR")]')

     print(title, price)
    
#driver.close()
```

This is just the first part of my code but I can't really continue without getting this to work. If anyone has some ideas on what I'm doing wrong that would be amazing! It's been driving me crazy. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I noticed a few issues with your code. First of all, I believe that when entering this page, first google will show you the "I agree to terms and conditions" popup before showing you the content of the page, therefore you need to first click on that button.

Also, you should use the find_elements_by_xpath function directly on driver instead of using the page content, as this also allows you to render the javascript content. You can find more info here: [python tree.xpath return empty list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59767068/python-tree-xpath-return-empty-list)

I used the following code to scrape the titles. (I also changed the xpaths to do so, by extracting them directly from google chrome. You can do that by right clicking on an element -> inspect and in the elements tab where the element is, you can right click -> copy -> Copy xpath)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

# I used these for the code to work on my windows subsystem linux
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument('--no-sandbox') 
option.add_argument('--disable-dev-sh-usage')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=option)
URL = 'https://www.google.com/travel/flights/searchtfs=CBwQAhopagwIAxIIL20vMHBseTASCjIwMjEtMTItMjNyDQgDEgkvbS8wMWYwOHIaKWoNCAMSCS9tLzAxZjA4chIKMjAyMS0xMi0yN3IMCAMSCC9tLzBwbHkwcAGCAQsI____________AUABSAGYAQE&tfu=EgYIAhAAGAA'

driver.get(URL)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="yDmH0d"]/c-wiz/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/form/div[1]/div/button/span').click() # this is necessary to pres the I agree button

elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="yDmH0d"]/c-wiz[2]/div/div[2]/div/c-wiz/div/c-wiz/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/c-wiz/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/ol/li')

for flight_tree in elements:
     title = flight_tree.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@class="W6bZuc YMlIz"]').text

     print(title)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below code, with screen maximized and having explicit waits and could successfully extract the information, please see below :

**Sample code :**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.google.com/travel/flights/searchtfs=CBwQAhopagwIAxIIL20vMHBseTASCjIwMjEtMTItMjNyDQgDEgkvbS8wMWYwOHIaKWoNCAMSCS9tLzAxZjA4chIKMjAyMS0xMi0yN3IMCAMSCC9tLzBwbHkwcAGCAQsI____________AUABSAGYAQE&tfu=EgYIAhAAGAA")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
titles = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div/descendant::h3")))

for name in titles:
  print(name.text)
  price = name.find_element(By.XPATH, "./../following-sibling::div/descendant::span[2]").text
  print(price)
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Output :**

```
Tokyo
₹38,473
Mumbai
₹3,515
Dubai
₹15,846
```

Comment: Thank you for the response I really appreciate it! I tried this and it did work but its only pulling flight info from the home page of google flights. How would the code look for the url to a specific flight like I have in my code? When I try it on that page with the corresponding xpath It doesn't work. Thank you!

Comment: Can you give me that new url ?

Comment: Yes of course! 

https://www.google.com/travel/flights/search?tfs=CBwQAhopagwIAxIIL20vMHBseTASCjIwMjEtMTItMjNyDQgDEgkvbS8wMWYwOHIaKWoNCAMSCS9tLzAxZjA4chIKMjAyMS0xMi0yN3IMCAMSCC9tLzBwbHkwcAGCAQsI____________AUABSAGYAQE

Maybe I'm not extracting the correct HTML tags but thank you for the help!